# Rails blog click save article the article content format would be broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails

the article content:

````
```ruby
   def hello
    puts "hello world!"
   end
```
````

but i click save button the `article content` occur issue.

[after save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQzjc.png)

and click update would occur some thing.

every time `update` article, the article content will be re-format. not know why it will be add some `space`

log show:

````
    [["text", "```ruby\r\ndef hello\r\nputs \"hello world!\"\r\nend\r\n```"]
````

what happened ?

what is the issue ?

Comment: Don't use screenshots for text output. That being said, what is the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>It seems you have `\r` in the request, a quick fix would be using`.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "\n")` to replace all `\r\n` with `\n`.</strike>

After discussing with author, the problem was because `haml` does not indent white spaces in code snippet properly.  Switching to `erb` fixed this problem.